# Excel application events: How to automatically reset WithEvents variable after a runtime error?

Tags: excel, events, vba

I use PERSONAL.XLSB to execute global macros.  Within it, I also listen to application events by doing this in the `ThisWorkbook` object:

```
Dim WithEvents app As Application
Private Sub Workbook_Open()

    Set app = Application

End Sub
```

Now I can listen to all workbook events without having to wire up an event to each workbook.

The problem is that, whenever a macro throws an exception and causes me to have to *End* the macro, all global variables get nuked, so the `app` variable gets set to `Nothing` which causes all global events to no longer fire.

Is there some way I can have this variable automatically set back to an instance of `Application` whenever it gets nulled out?

Answer (score 3):

You can create a public function which contains the default values of all the global variable then call that function under your error handle. An example:

```
Dim WithEvents app As Application
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
  On Error GoTo reset
    Set app = Application
  On Error Goto 0   ' Turn off error trapping. 
  Exit Sub
Reset:
    Call resetvar
End Sub

Public Sub Resetvar()
    Set app = Application
End Sub
```